# How to validate a hash from a magento database using C#

Tags: c#, magento, encryption, hash

I have a database that contains customers imported from a magento database and I was wondering if it's possible to use the hash that I already have or if the only way is to ask all customers to change their password.

My app is using C# I've tried to use MD5 but the result it's not the same.

Password: 741963
Magento Hash: c8cb61663ba8b4adadc16687d5e2a636:W0
C# simple MD5: CDE8E3E58AB6E2D16CBE1A0EE19FE3A3

I've read that Magento uses a salted hash and that the salt is after the colon but I'm not sure how to use it.

If someone has a clue of how to solve that..

Thanks!

Comment: You want to remove the salt and decrypt the md5 to plain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Storing passwords in magento way.**

Magento is not using md5-hash to store the password.

It is using salted md5. :)

Let me explain, Before md5-ing the password typed by the user, Salt string will be concatenated to the password then It will be encrypted.

1. For example If a user types password **123456**, It will be concatenated to the random generated salt string, Here Lets assume our salt string is, **salted_rdom_val**.
2. The two values will be concatenated like this **123456salted_rdom_val**
3. Now they will go to the md5() function. That will produce something like 654d2ea4a4dd03bc728b8933c61be75d
4. After Generating the md5, 
   the md5 will be concatenated with the random salt with **:** in the middle. 
   like this.

   **2c433dcfc6e3dd9973195bac308482e3:salted_rdom_val**
5. So, Now the table(customer_entity_varchar) will have this value

**Authenticating Customer in a magento way**

Magento authentication will be done in following steps.

1. Assume,Email availability check is done already, Its nothing but checking whether the user is registered in the magento site.
2. First they will receive the password from the customer's form. Lets assume the plain text as 'password'
3. Now, We ill get the customer's exact password by using the email id he provided.

For ex.

```
$orig_pass = 2c433dcfc6e3dd9973195bac308482e3:salted_rdom_val;
```

4. Magento will explode this string with the ":" parameter. Explode will make the two parts to be stored as an array.

Now we have two values in exploded array.

```
$exploded[0]= 2c433dcfc6e3dd9973195bac308482e3;

$exploded[1] = salted_rdom_val;
```

5. Here comes the authentication part, Magento will concatenate the $exploded[1] with the password plain text which is 'password'

   $variable = $password.$exploded[1];

   $variable = passwordsalted_rdom_val;

And It will do the hashing,

```
md5($variable);

md5(passwordsalted_rdom_va);

The output of md5() is 2b339a6b211bc1436cd1e45e2db7f8d6.
```

6. Now magento will check both the hashes, If the hashes are same, The session will be created.

Otherwise, You will be having an error message "Please check you email id and password."

This is how magento validates the password of the customer, You can call some csharp wrappers to acheive the same.

Comment: I think your approach is wrong. Salt should be added in front of password not behind.

Comment: Have you had a chance to check it?

Comment: I checked it and its Salt+Password as Hamlet says

Answer (score 1):

As you see there is a colon in your `Magento` hash. The `W0` after the colon is salt. The algoritm of hashing password is

```
hash(salt + password)
```

If you try to calc MD5 of `W0741963` you will get correct hash `c8cb61663ba8b4adadc16687d5e2a636`.